# How to resolve groovy.lang.MissingMethodException?

Tags: groovy, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, quartz-core

How to resolve groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: methodMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: []?

In my project I have two plugins and I am getting this exception at start-up for one of the plugins (All the functionality of this plugin is fine)

I've got the exception on this line for 'findAllByStatus'

```
def newItemList = Item.findAllByStatus(ItemStatus.NEW)
```

I have imported Item.groovy in current service class, also the service class is being created at start-up when quartz is starting. I'm not sure if it is related to quartz or not.

Item is a domain class.

```
class Item implements Serializable {    

    ItemStatus status
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    def updateLastUpdated(){
        lastUpdated = new Date()
    }
    static hasMany = [itemProperties : ItemProperty]
    static mapping = {
        table 'xcomms_item'
        datasource 'xcomms'
    }
    static constraints = {
        batch nullable:true
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 13 * id.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if ((obj != null) && (obj instanceof Item) && (((Item)obj).id.equals(this.id))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

The stack trace:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: xcomms.Item.methodMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
at xcomms.CommunicationBatchProcessService.communicationProcesss(CommunicationBatchProcessService.groovy:53)
at xcomms.AutomatedCommunicationJob.execute(AutomatedCommunicationJob.groovy:16)
at grails.plugin.quartz2.GrailsArtefactJob.execute(GrailsArtefactJob.java:59)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
2013-11-14 14:20:00,112 [QuartzJobCluster_Worker-2] ERROR quartz2.JobErrorLoggerListener  - Exception thrown in job:xcomms.AutomatedCommunicationJob
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: xcomms.communication.exception.CommunicationProcessException: Error in processing communication batch [See nested exception: xcomms.communication.exception.CommunicationProcessException: Error in processing communication batch]
at grails.plugin.quartz2.GrailsArtefactJob.execute(GrailsArtefactJob.java:66)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
Caused by: xcomms.communication.exception.CommunicationProcessException: Error in processing communication batch
at xcomms.AutomatedCommunicationJob.execute(AutomatedCommunicationJob.groovy:19)
at grails.plugin.quartz2.GrailsArtefactJob.execute(GrailsArtefactJob.java:59)
... 2 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: xcomms.Item.methodMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
at xcomms.CommunicationBatchProcessService.communicationProcesss(CommunicationBatchProcessService.groovy:53)
at xcomms.AutomatedCommunicationJob.execute(AutomatedCommunicationJob.groovy:16)
... 3 more
```

ItemStatus is:

```
public enum  ItemStatus {

NEW(0,"New"),BATCHED(1,"Batched"),SENT(2,"Sent")

final int id
final String name

private ItemStatus(int id, String name) { this.id = id; this.name = name;}
static ItemStatus getById(int i){
    for( entry in ItemStatus.values() ){
        if(entry.id == i)
            return entry
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `Item.findAllByStatus` and what's the full stack trace?  (Or at least 10 or so lines from the top of it)

Comment: @tim_yates I've called 'Item.findAllByStatus' in a service class which is 'xcomms.CommunicationBatchProcessService'

Comment: Is ItemStatus.NEW of type ItemStatus?

When you say, `Item.findAllByStatus` it is expecting something of type ItemStatus.

Can you include the code for ItemStatus?

Comment: ItemStatus.NEW ia a type of ItemStatus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. 
At the start-up, quartz loads service class but it couldn't execute GORM commands at this point. Then I changed it to the native sql `select * from xcomms_item where status = 0` . Now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done to solve this problem is to postpone the start of the Quartz Scheduler. As Ima said, there is a kind of race condition that makes GORM not available until the Grails app has completely started. If you try to use it before, you get a `MissingMethodException`.

My solution involved disabling the Quartz Scheduler `autoStartup` (see https://github.com/9ci/grails-quartz2/blob/07ecde5baa59e20f99c05302c61137617c08fc81/src/groovy/grails/plugin/quartz2/QuartzFactoryBean.groovy#L61) and to `start()` it in the `Bootstrap.groovy` after all the initialization was done.

This is the config to prevent autoStartup:

```
grails {
    plugin {
        quartz2 {
            autoStartup = false
        }
    }
}
```

Using this way you don't have to give up using GORM, as Ima suggested.